# React Redux persist from PouchDB

Tags: reactjs, redux, pouchdb, redux-persist

I'm working on a React/Redux application and I want to persist only one reducer in a db (because of large data), Have you an idea if it possible ?
I want to Rehydrate my Reducer from this DB

Comment: I'm assuming it must be possible, and there is also an adapter for pouchdb: https://github.com/yanick/redux-persist-pouchdb

Comment: Have you a demo for that please ? It's for pwa or only react-native ?

Comment: No idea sorry, I just had a brief look at the github project for redux-persist.